# Mathematica combinatorica package: avoid graphs rendering

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm working with quite large graphs in notebook (I'm not a Mathematica expert).

Every time I load or manipulate a graph with instructions like these:

```
g = Import["out.graphml", "Graph"] or
g = VertexAdd[g, "aux"]
```

the graph is displayed in the result but the rendering is very very slow.

Is there a way to disable graph rendering in notebook?

Comment: @image_doctor, Vor: I'm pretty sure that the parentheses on the second line should be replaced by square brackets, otherwise it gives a syntax error.

Comment: @IstvánZachar: thanks, typo corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The graphical portion of any Mathematica output can be suppressed by placing a semicolon at the end of the line.

```
g = Import["out.graphml", "Graph"];
g = VertexAdd(g, "aux");
```

Comment: ... trivial question, quick answer! Thanks! :-)